# ¿Por qué me dice que translate() no es una función?

Tags: javascript, json

Espero puedan ayudarme en esto: Siempre que ingreso el texto y doy click al boton el error que arroja este error:
Uncaught TypeError: translate is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14:35)

```js
async function translate() {
    console.log("Entré");
    const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    const response = await fetch('lexmau.json'); // Replace with your JSON endpoint or URL
    const data = await response.json();
    const dictionary = data.dictionary;
  
    const words = inputText.split(/\s+/);
    const translatedWords = words.map(word => {
      const foundWord = dictionary.find(item => item.Form.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase());
      return foundWord ? foundWord.Gloss : word;
    });
  
    document.getElementById('outputText').innerText = translatedWords.join(' ');
  }
```

```css
body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        
        .container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 50px auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        
        button {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        button:hover {
            background-color: #0056b3;
        }
        
        .output {
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Traductor Mazateco</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Traductor Mazateco a Español</h1>
    <textarea id="inputText" placeholder="Ingresa el texto en Mazateco"></textarea>
    <button onclick="translate()">Traducir</button>
    <div id="outputText" class="output"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No soy experto en JS pero yo, si logré entrar:

```js
function translatex() {
  console.log("Yo si entré. OCHOA");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="translatex()">Probar</button>
```

Lo que no te funcionará es como tu lo tienes ya que `translate()` es un método o función existente utilizado para dibujos de Canvas 2D.

[Más sobre translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate)

Si lo piensas bien, era super raro que una palabra tan "ampliamente usada en programación" no fuera ya una función de JS. Algo como querer usar sort, array, type, o símiles.